# ruby on rails rest api with ruby for login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to implement a ruby api for login page with ruby on rails backend in android mobile application, As i am new to this kindly help me to complete my task, and please tell the way to implement an API
 Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not like this. Post what you have done so far. Post at lest your ideas about the task. Help us to help you.

Comment: i followed this (https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application) link to create api in ruby language

Comment: this (https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application) link contains idea about controllers only, I am not getting information about the views and Database

Comment: Maybe because an API is not supposed to necessarily have views. It should receive requests and return results to be used in one's application.

Comment: i agreed but what about backend views

Comment: Usually using an API key is more efficient than maintaining a session in your client and using that with cookies.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly there is no point to put -ve mark on this question, he is new in ruby, we can help him.

step 1: To make an api you have to deal with controllers and models there is no view for an api.

step 2: since you are new in rails read about rails routing, let me give you a brief idea, the router simply decide if a request comes on a url which controller and which action should trigger.

step 3: Once your action in the controller is trigger write your logic their or call a method in a model.

Step 4: Once you have done CRUD operation from the model return the response to the controller.

step 5 : Depending on the format weather the client want a `xml` or `json` encode it in `xml/json` and render it from the controller.

dats it :) hope it helps you

Comment: thanks @ashwini , now i have idea about it.. and of course my application's API is going in a right way as u have told me about routing and controller.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to quote the great thinkers, but the answer is: It depends!

You can either go it simple and use BASIC AUTHENTICATION for your app, or you can go the more-complex road of using other technologies, such as JWT (Json Web Token) or OAuth or whatnot...

I assume you are at just starting web development so I would suggest you start simple by using BASIC AUTH (over some https connection).

For the Rails part you just include the following directive in the controller you want protected:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "username", password: "secret", except: :index
```

So a simple controller would look like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except:  :index

  def index
    render plain: "Everyone can see me!"
  end

  def edit
    render plain: "I'm only accessible if you know the password"
  end
end
```

This example is directly copied from here: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

On the client side you need to provide the basic authentication credentials in the HTTP header like this:

```
"Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6c2VjcmV0"
```

using BASE64 to encode username and password like this (in javascript):

```
encoded = btoa(username + ":" + password);
```

The basics are covered here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

From there you can go and implement a simple username/password screen and provide the so generated header in all subsequent calls.

I hope this gets you started into the right direction. Don't shy away from asking and keep learning!

Eventually you may want to move on to more sophisticated access-token based authentication methods.

Best regards,
Steviee